# js sequelize multiple where in include not working

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize query with multiple where conditions in an include model:

```
const scrapingUrl = await db.ScrapingUrl.findOne({
            where: strong text{
                date_downloaded: null,
            },
            include: [ {
                model: db.Action,
                where: {
                    $or: {
                        hourly_scraping_limit: null,
                        scraping_counter: {
                            $or: {
                                $eq: null,
                                $lt: Sequelize.literal('Action.hourly_scraping_limit')
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    $or: {
                        hourly_scraping_limit_per_proxy: null,
                        scraping_counter_per_proxy: {
                            $or: {
                                $eq: null,
                                $lt: Sequelize.literal('Action.hourly_scraping_limit_per_proxy')
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                include: [ db.ScrapingContainer ]
            } ]
        });
```

It seems to ignore hourly_scraping_limit part and only filters for hourly_scraping_limit_per_proxy. The relevant query part is this:

```
$or: {
    hourly_scraping_limit: null,
    scraping_counter: {
        $or: {
            $eq: null,
            $lt: Sequelize.literal('Action.hourly_scraping_limit')
        }
    }
},
```

Sequelize logs the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT `ScrapingUrl`.`id`, `ScrapingUrl`.`action_id`, `ScrapingUrl`.`url`, `ScrapingUrl`.`date_added`, `ScrapingUrl`.`date_downloaded`, `ScrapingUrl`.`date_scraped`, `ScrapingUrl`.`success_pattern_found`, `ScrapingUrl`.`blocked_pattern_found`, `ScrapingUrl`.`scraping_blob_id`, `Action`.`id` AS `Action.id`, `Action`.`name` AS `Action.name`, `Action`.`scraping_container_id` AS `Action.scraping_container_id`, `Action`.`hourly_scraping_limit` AS `Action.hourly_scraping_limit`, `Action`.`hourly_scraping_limit_per_proxy` AS `Action.hourly_scraping_limit_per_proxy`, `Action`.`scraping_counter` AS `Action.scraping_counter`, `Action`.`scraping_counter_per_proxy` AS `Action.scraping_counter_per_proxy`, `Action`.`scraping_counter_last_reset` AS `Action.scraping_counter_last_reset`, `Action`.`scraping_success_pattern` AS `Action.scraping_success_pattern`, `Action`.`scraping_blocked_pattern` AS `Action.scraping_blocked_pattern`, `Action.ScrapingContainer`.`id` AS `Action.ScrapingContainer.id`, `Action.ScrapingContainer`.`name` AS `Action.ScrapingContainer.name` FROM `scraping_urls` AS `ScrapingUrl` INNER JOIN `actions` AS `Action` ON `ScrapingUrl`.`action_id` = `Action`.`id` AND ((`Action`.`hourly_scraping_limit_per_proxy` IS NULL OR (`Action`.`scraping_counter_per_proxy` IS NULL OR `Action`.`scraping_counter_per_proxy` < Action.hourly_scraping_limit_per_proxy))) LEFT OUTER JOIN `scraping_containers` AS `Action.ScrapingContainer` ON `Action`.`scraping_container_id` = `Action.ScrapingContainer`.`id` WHERE `ScrapingUrl`.`date_downloaded` IS NULL LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The $or is not properly formed. I think that's the issue. Example:

```
where: {
  '$or': [
    {bla: true},
    {bla: false}
  ]
}
```

Translates to:

```
WHERE bla = true OR bla = false
```

If you need to nest $or:

```
where: {
  '$or': [
    {'$or': [{foo: true, bar: false}, {foo: false, bar: true}]},
    {'$or': [{bla: true, ble: false}, {bla: false, ble: true}]},
  ]
}
```

Translates to:

```
WHERE ((foo = true AND bar = false) OR (foo = false AND bar = true)) OR ((foo = false AND bar = true) OR (foo = true AND bar = false))
```